# Winapi different background colors for two static text elements

Tags: c++, winapi, text, colors, static

How do I change the background color of 2 static text elements separately, each one having a different background color

Code:

```
background1 = CreateWindow("STATIC","",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 0,0,800,20, hwnd , NULL, NULL, NULL);
background2 = CreateWindow("STATIC","",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 0,70,800,500, hwnd , NULL, NULL, NULL);


case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {  
         HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
         SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,255));
         SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,255));

         if (hbrBkgnd == NULL){
             hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,55));
         }
         return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
    }
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lparam contains a static control window handle, so you can check it to figure out which control is being redrawn.

```
if(reinterpret_cast<::HWND>(lParam) == background1)
{
    // set background for control 1...
}
else // set backgrounds for other controls
```